# Magento IWD one page checkout, show shipping cost

Tags: shipping, onepage-checkout

UPDATE:

### I need to use the ajax function, when the shipping is updated or when voucher code is applied the fees should be added. I can not find out how to do this.

using IWD one page checkout.

Before total amount I want to show the total calculated shipping cost incl taxes. Have have got the costs etc working for the products and total. But I can not get the shipping cost, even when I copy code for showing this I get errors.

Can you please help me, going crazy!?

Here is the code i am using for products and total

```
<?php

    $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

    foreach($items as $item) { ?>
        <h5 style="color:#3f3f3f; font-size:14px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:5px; padding-right: 15px;"><?php echo $item->getQty(); ?> qty, <?php echo $item->getName(); ?>: <div style="float: right;color:#3f3f3f; font-size:14px;"><?php echo number_format((float)$item->getPriceInclTax()*$item->getQty(), 2, '.', ''); ?> €</div></h5>

   <? }
?>



              <h5 class="grand_total" style="padding-right: 15px;"><?php echo $this->__('Total Amount to Pay:')?><span style="float: right;color:#3f3f3f; font-size:16px;"><?php echo Mage::helper('opc')->getGrandTotal()?></span></h5>
```

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have same problem